# Django Rest Framework - image url on reverse foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access the url of an `ImageField` on a model related through a reverse-`ForeignKey`. I have attempted various possible options based on examples in the docs, but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

---

## models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(... )

    @property
        def default_image(self):
            ... ...
            return image # <=== returns from the CarImage model

class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car) # <=== no related_name set, but technically we could use carimage_set
    image = models.ImageField(... ...)
```

---

## serializers.py (attempt)

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... ...
    image = fields.SerializerMethodField('get_image')

    class Meta:
        mode = Car

    def get_image(self, obj):
        return '%s' % obj.default_image.url
```

---

## exception

`'SortedDictWithMetadata' object has no attribute 'default_image'`

Comment: You can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513705/python-property-decorator

Comment: That's not the issue. The new reverse relationships in DRF 2.3 seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new DRF 2.3 seems to be helpful with reverse relationships and has solved my issues.

### [DRF 2.3 Announcement](http://django-rest-framework.org/topics/2.3-announcement.html)

For example, in REST framework 2.2, reverse relationships needed to be included explicitly on a serializer class.

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = Blog
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'created', 'comments')
```

As of 2.3, you can simply include the field name, and the appropriate serializer field will automatically be used for the relationship.

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   """Don't need to specify the 'comments' field explicitly anymore."""
   class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'created', 'comments')
```