# python class: store a variable in the class and use it later

Tags: python

First I have to say that I'm not a professional python programmer,
so I might ask some really stupid questions, please bear with me...

Here is the idea:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myValue = ''
    def function1(self, something):
        self.myValue = something
    def function2(self):
        print self.myValue

foo = Foo()
foo.function1("target") --> I want to store the value "target" in the class and use it later
foo.function2()  --> I want to print out "target"
```

Obviously, this is really wrong, but I don't know how how to correct it.

If you can give me some directions, I'll really appreciate it!

Comment: Change `self.Value` to `self.myValue`.

Comment: You're almost there.  Spell it the same in all of your methods and try again.

Comment: Rather than changing the original question, accept an answer. StackOverflow is intended to be not just a quick way of getting good answers to your questions, but also a record of questions and answers that will be useful for other people. By editing your question, you've made it incomprehensible, because the code you have is now *correct*, so people like myself who didn't see the original are confused when you say "this is really wrong."

Comment: I know, I'm just thinking that I might have some problems which are not explained very well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also can try to take a look at @property decorator:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._myValue = None

    @property
    def myValue(self):
        print self._myValue
        return self._myValue

    @myValue.setter
    def myValue(self, something):
        self._myValue = something

foo = Foo()
foo.myValue = 10
foo.myValue
```

Find more on this here [Real world example about how to use property feature in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304040/real-world-example-about-how-to-use-property-feature-in-python)

Comment: I'm thinking that the code I wrote was not efficient enough...
Maybe "decorator" is what I should dig in.
Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @OwenLiu you are welcome, note that property can be implemented using property method as well

Answer (score 1):

You're close, just a few typos. In `function2` it should say `myValue`:

```
def function2(self):
    print self.myValue
```

And to call `function2` add an empty set of parentheses:

```
foo.function2()
```