# What is a property attribute and how do I use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a class that takes 2 coordinates and returns the slope and distance of the respective coordinates.
It works fine but, apparently, what I did was wrong and was supposed to give an error.

My code:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, coord1, coord2):

        self.coord1 = coord1
        self.coord2 = coord2

    def distance(self):

        return math.sqrt( ((self.coord1[0]-self.coord2[0])**2)+((self.coord1[1]-self.coord2[1])**2) )

    def slope(self):

        c = self.coord2[0]-self.coord1[0]
        d = self.coord2[1]-self.coord1[1]
        if d==0:
            return "zero"
        elif c==0:
            return "Infinity"
        else:
            return d/c

line1=Line((8,3),(0,-4))
print(line1.distance())
print(line1.slope())
```

```
RESTART: C:\Users.....\Classes.py
10.63014581273465 **The result is right...?**
0.875
```

I get the right output, but this is how I am *supposed* to do it:

```
>>> line1=Line((8,3),(0,-4))
>>> line1.distance()
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line
1, in <module>TypeError: 'float' object is not callable  **This is like mine but error?**
>>> line1.slope()
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>TypeError:
    'float' object is not callable **Just like mine but error?**
>>> line1.distance
10.63
>>> line1.slope
0.875
```

What is the difference and is mine wrong?

Comment: make distance a variable, not a function

Comment: Related reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: This may sound real stupid but im a beginner ....but how do i do that?

Comment: As suggested by @Kevin, checkout the documentation. You can also just search a bit for `python`, `property`, `decorator`. There are multiple threads around here as well, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304040/real-world-example-about-how-to-use-property-feature-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put `property decorator` behind the func [some useful docs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

```
@property
def distance(self):
    ...

@property
def slope(self):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped!!! But why? I really don't understand why? What is a property decorator?

Comment: A property is an application of the descriptor protocol. Put briefly, `line1.distance` doesn't return the value of an instance attribute, but the return value of a call to `Line.distance.__get__(line1, Line)`

Answer (score -2):

you need distance/slope to be variables

```
class Line: 

def __init__(self, coord1, coord2):

    self.coord1 = coord1
    self.coord2 = coord2
    self.distance = self.get_distance()
    self.slope = self.get_slope()

def get_distance(self):

    return math.sqrt( ((self.coord1[0]-self.coord2[0])**2)+((self.coord1[1]-self.coord2[1])**2) )



def get_slope(self):

    c = self.coord2[0]-self.coord1[0]
    d = self.coord2[1]-self.coord1[1]
    if d==0:
        return "zero"
    elif c==0:
        return "Infinity"
    else:
        return d/c
```

This way, distance/slope are floats, and not functions; so you'll get the error that you're after

Comment: Thank you! But below is simpler and worked exactly like it should.

Comment: it's "simpler" but you don't understand it.  Decorators are a bit more advanced than what I showed

Comment: This is unlikely to be what the assignment had in mind. In particular, you'll need to manually call `get_distance` and `get_slope` manually each time you change one of the coordinates.