# Usefulness of property decorator in python for mutable attributes

Tags: python, oop, properties

Trying to understand the benefit of properties in Python when we need to be able to set them. Explicitly looking to see the pros/cons of the two techniques.

What are the benefits of using the @property with @prop.setter in Python:

```
class Foo2:

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        self._prop = value
```

Compared to simply setting the attribute without the property decorator?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real world example about how to use property feature in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304040/real-world-example-about-how-to-use-property-feature-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an attribute that *can't be deleted*:

```
>>> f = Foo2('bar')
>>> f.prop
'bar'
>>> f.prop = 'spam'
>>> f.prop
'spam'
>>> del f.prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't delete attribute
```

Compare this to the `Foo().prop` attribute, which can be deleted:

```
>>> f = Foo('bar')
>>> f.prop
'bar'
>>> del f.prop
>>> f.prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'prop'
```

Apart from that, or if you added a `@prop.deleter` handler, there is not really any advantage to creating such a property. Delegating to a function what normal attribute access can do is not that useful.

Property setters or getters are much more useful when they do *something in addition* to just setting the attribute, like validation or transformation.

For example, the setter could enforce that values are always integers, including setting a default value if conversion to an integer fails:

```
@prop.setter
def prop(self, value):
    try:
        self._prop = int(prop)
    except ValueError:
        self._prop = 0
```

In other programming languages such as Java, you can't easily convert attributes to getters and setters (there is no equivalent concept to Python properties in Java) without having to re-write all access to those attributes everywhere in your code-base, so in those languages you often see advice to start out with getters and setters. **This doesn't apply to Python**, you can trivially turn existing attributes into properties without having to change any code using those attributes.