# Confusied about Descriptor Behaviour

Tags: python, class, descriptor

I'm trying to understand descriptors and  wrote a simple example that practically emulates the given one:

```
class Descriptor:
    
    
    def __set_name__(self,obj,name): 
        self.name=name
        
    def __set__(self,obj,valor): 
        
        if (self.name).title()=='Nombre':
            if type(valor)!=str:
                raise TypeError('No es un string')
            else:
                print(f'Estamos cambiando el atributo nombre de {obj} a {valor}')
                setattr(obj,self.name,valor) 
                
        else: print('Hola')
            
    def __get__(self,obj,owner):
        
        return getattr(obj,self.name)  
    
class Prueba:
    
    nombre=Descriptor()
    apellido=Descriptor()
    print(nombre.__dict__)
    print(apellido.__dict__)
    
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellido):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.apellido=apellido
            
        
baz=Prueba('foo','bar')

print(baz.__dict__)
```

Which makes the Jupyter Kernel crash (had never happened before).

If I change every `nombre` or `apellido`, I get:

```
{}
{}
Hola
Hola
{}
```

So somehow the instances of the Descriptor class are empty. Yet when I make Descriptor print `self.name` in **`set` **it works. I'm very confused about how to use them to simplify properties.

Comment: For me the code falls with a `RecursionError` which is expected because `setattr(obj,self.name,valor)` calls the `__set__` method of `Descriptor`.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why setattr calls `__set__` again?

Comment: (1) `setattr(obj, 'nombre', valor)` does the same as (2) `obj.nombre = valor` would. Because `obj.nombre` is a descriptor, both (1) and (2) result in the descriptor's `__set__` method being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is an infinite regress in the `__get__` and `__set__` methods of the descriptor.  For the sake of example, let's focus just on the descriptor object for the `nombre` attribute, which has `self.name == 'nombre'`.

When you initialise an instance of `Prueba`:

1. In `__init__`, executing `self.nombre = nombre` invokes the descriptor's `__set__` method (as expected)
2. That `__set__` method invokes `setattr(obj, 'nombre', valor)` (because the descriptor's `self.name` is `'nombre'`)
3. The value of object's `nombre` attribute is the descriptor itself. So that `setattr` call invokes `__set__` in the descriptor again.

So steps 2 and 3 repeat cyclically until the recursion depth is exceeded.

Similarly, a call to `__get__` executes `getattr(obj, 'nombre')`.  But `obj.nombre` which is the descriptor object itself, so the result is another call to the descriptor's `__get__`, and so on in an infinite cycle.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names) show a way that you can programmatically store attribute values using a "private" name that avoids this regress.

So your example descriptor becomes:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __set_name__(self,obj,name): 
        self.name=name
        self.private_name = '_' + name
        
    def __set__(self,obj,valor): 
        if (self.name).title()=='Nombre':
            if type(valor)!=str:
                raise TypeError('No es un string')
            else:
                print(f'Estamos cambiando el atributo nombre de {obj} a {valor}')
                setattr(obj,self.private_name,valor) 
                
        else: print('Hola')
            
    def __get__(self,obj,owner):
        return getattr(obj,self.private_name)
```

With this in place, your example of:

```
baz=Prueba('foo','bar')
print(baz.__dict__)
```

now gives:

```
{}
{}
Estamos cambiando el atributo nombre de <__main__.Prueba object at 0x7f04e0220ee0> a foo
Hola
{'_nombre': 'foo'}
```

and `print(baz.nombre)` prints `foo`.

Comment: I believe you are saying that `__init__` in Prueba is calling `__set__` because it's setting the attribute `set` (which seems not to be the set instance I declared before??). Then, I call self.name expecting to read the attribute easily, but instead, since I have a descriptor called `name` inside the class, I go to `__get__` and execute ``getattr``. Am I right? If so, I still don't understand what the exact problem with getattr is. Is it that, inside it, it's calling self.name again, thus initializing ``__get__`` another time?

Comment: I edited the answer to be clearer about this. The core problem is that the value of the object's `nombre` attribute is the descriptor object. So we need to find another attribute name (for example `_nombre`) in which to store the value itself.

Comment: So doing setattr(object, attribute, value) is the same as object.attribute=value, which is exactly what I'd called before, right? It's a bit weird because I think that some names are dummy when they aren't. For example, in the `__init__`, where I use `nombre` for both an input variable and the descriptor itself, how does it know which is which? Sorry for these questions, but I'm new to Python (and programming in general except some Matlab) and everything is a rabbit hole.

Comment: *how does it know which is which?* In that case, it's because the variable in the function's local scope (`nombre`) is separate from the attribute in the object's namespace (`self.nombre`). That doesn't cause problems and is a common Python idiom, especially in constructors.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. So to recap, I have defined an _attribute_ which is of type *descriptor*, just as I could have assigned it a string, int or whatever, and I access it  with obj.atr. (I think many other objects have or are descriptors, but I mean a customised one). So the effect this has is that when doing certain operations such as reading, assigning or deleting, instead of behaving 'normally' like in regular python variables, it does exactly what I programmed in its ``get`` and ``set`` methods. And for these custom descriptors to be generated, I must always instantiate them first.

Comment: Sounds like you got it! One thing to add - if you haven't seen this already, take a look at **properties** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304040/real-world-example-about-how-to-use-property-feature-in-python). These allow you to create the kind of descriptor that you were using here, but without writing so much explicit code.